# ControlTemplate trigger on a subelement

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, datepicker

I want to increase the size of the border of a DatePicker when it has focus. In the TextBox style the following works nicely when used with a border BorderBase in the ControlTemplate.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsFocused" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="BorderBase" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" TargetName="BorderBase" Value="3"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

For DatePicker this does not work since the DatePickerTextBox inside the DatePicker has the actual focus. On the [DatePicker style page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468215.aspx) the visual states are listed. The TextBox does have a Focused state, but the DatePicker only has a Focused state for when the input invalid.

How do you guys suggest I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about setting your Trigger on `HasKeyboardFocus` instead of `IsFocused`? I think that one will return true if any child element contains focus

Comment: Thanks, I bound to IsKeyboardFocusWithin. Works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

How about naming the `TextBox` and specifying a respective [`Trigger.SourceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger.sourcename.aspx)?